# Non-preemptive kernel and computational processes

Tags: linux-kernel, preemption

I've read in a text book that a non-preemptive kernel has an advantage when dealing with computational processes. I couldn't understand what is the reason for this. I know that non-preemptive kernel allows to run 1 process each time but why is that an advantage for computational process?

Comment: by non pre emptive you mean co-operative? And compared to what?

Comment: "I know that non-preemptive kernel allows to run 1 process each time..." - You probably read the book in a wrong way: A *non-preemptive kernel* limits only number of processes which runs in the **kernel mode**. It is very possible several processes to run in the **user mode** at once.